# Can enumerate be used to count the occurrence of some condition?

Tags: python, list, enumeration

I want to count how many times the item of a list satisfy one condition. For example a[i] > 1:

```
a = [2,4,3,0]

counter = 0
for value in a:
    if value > 1:
        counter += 1
```

Is it possible to use the `enumerate` function to do it and avoid the counter += 1?

As is made in a loop:

```
for i,j in enumerate(list(xrange(5))):
    print i
    print j
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension- bonus points because they're damn fast (list comps are implemented in C)

```
a = [2,3,4,0]
count = len([i for i in a if i > 1])
# Or, to avoid a temporary list: (courtesy of John Kugelman)
count = sum(1 for i in a if i > 1)
```

Explain:

```
len(...) # Gives the number of terms in the list
[i for i in a ... ] # Works like a for loop- this list is composed of pieces named i, where
                    # i is each term in a
[ ... if i > 1] # As long as that i is > 1.

# The sum() method does the same thing, but slightly more memory-efficient
```

Comment: But if the size of list becomes too large, you'll be using extra space to create the list...

Comment: @hashcode55 The method presented in the original question will do the same by creating the `list(xrange(5))`

Comment: @JohnKugelman won't `sum()` behind the curtain will also create a list? I mean I thought it'll create a list and just aggregate it.

Comment: @hashcode55 it probably doesn't- it looks like it's using generator syntax so it should be lazy and never hold the whole thing in memory- like what xrange does (vs. python2 range creating the list)

Comment: @Delioth I totally agree with that!